# Query that will split a string into several columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, substring

I need a query that will split a string into several columns like this:

```
[text](
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE ([vDescricao] VARCHAR(100))
    
    INSERT INTO @TABLE
    SELECT 
        [descricao]
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES
        ('[A/3] - 7'),
        ('[B/3] - 50'),
        ('[C/2] - 1.3.1'),
        ('[D/1] - 1.4'),
        ('[E/3] - 33'),
        ('[F/4f] - 1.2.1.2.1'),
        ('[GG/4] -  1.2.1.4.2')
    )D([descricao]);)
```

The desired result is:

[image]

I created the following code:

```
SELECT 
    [vDescricao]

    ,[vTipo] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX('[', vDescricao)+1,
        CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao) - CHARINDEX('[', vDescricao)-1
        )

    ,[vNivel] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao)+1,
        CHARINDEX(']', vDescricao) - CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao)-1
        )

    ,[vCodigo] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', vDescricao)+3,
        LEN(vDescricao) - CHARINDEX(' - ', vDescricao)
        )

FROM @TABLE
```

This is not clean code (several repetitions, no design patterns). It works.

what is a better solution?

Maybe can I use some function, with variables.

```
SELECT 
    [vDescricao]

    ,[vTipo] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX('[', vDescricao)+1,
        CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao) - CHARINDEX('[', vDescricao)-1
        )

    ,[vNivel] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao)+1,
        CHARINDEX(']', vDescricao) - CHARINDEX('/', vDescricao)-1
        )

    ,[vCodigo] = SUBSTRING(
        vDescricao,
        CHARINDEX(' - ', vDescricao)+3,
        LEN(vDescricao) - CHARINDEX(' - ', vDescricao)
        )

FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: SQL is not optimized for this kind of processing. Rather, you are expected to either do this kind of work on the client or build the schema with these fields in the first place. The result is this kind of repetition is normal in SQL, and it's painful on purpose, to encourage you do the work at the presentation level where it belongs.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: "it seems" is not clear ro helpful. Define "better". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 3):

Just another option using a bit of JSON

```
Select A.*
      ,Pos1 = trim(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]'))
      ,Pos2 = trim(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
      ,Pos3 = trim(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]'))
 From  @TABLE A
 Cross Apply ( values ( replace(replace(replace([vDescricao],'[',''),']',''),'-','/') ) ) B(CleanString)
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(CleanString,'/','","')+'"]') ) C(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code works and seems relevant for your use case.

If you are looking to avoid repeating yourself, you can move some of the expressions to a subquery - or a lateral join - although that's a trade-off  that also increases the complexity of the query:

```
select t.vDescricao,
    substring(t.vDescricao, i.bracket_open + 1, i.slash - i.bracket_open  - 1) vTipo,
    substring(t.vDescricao, i.slash + 1,        i.bracket_close - i.slash - 1) vNivel,
    substring(t.vDescricao, i.dash + 3,         len(vDescricao) - i.dash     ) vCodigo
from @table t
cross apply ( 
    values (
        charindex('[',   vDescricao), 
        charindex(']',   vDescricao),
        charindex('/',   vDescricao),
        charindex(' - ', vDescricao)
    ) 
) i (bracket_open, bracket_close, slash, dash)
```

| vDescricao | vTipo | vNivel | vCodigo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [A/3] - 7 | A | 3 | 7 |
| [B/3] - 50 | B | 3 | 50 |
| [C/2] - 1.3.1 | C | 2 | 1.3.1 |
| [D/1] - 1.4 | D | 1 | 1.4 |
| [E/3] - 33 | E | 3 | 33 |
| [F/4f] - 1.2.1.2.1 | F | 4f | 1.2.1.2.1 |
| [GG/4] - 1.2.1.4.2 | GG | 4 | 1.2.1.4.2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PAeLuBKl)

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL is using XML and XQuery to tokenize a string.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (vDescricao VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @tbl (vDescricao) VALUES
('[A/3] - 7'),
('[B/3] - 50'),
('[C/2] - 1.3.1'),
('[D/1] - 1.4'),
('[E/3] - 33'),
('[F/4f] - 1.2.1.2.1'),
('[GG/4] -  1.2.1.4.2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , vTipo = c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
    , vNivel = c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
    , vCodigo = c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(TRANSLATE(TRIM('[' FROM vDescricao),']-','//'),'/', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| vDescricao | vTipo | vNivel | vCodigo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [A/3] - 7 | A | 3 | 7 |
| [B/3] - 50 | B | 3 | 50 |
| [C/2] - 1.3.1 | C | 2 | 1.3.1 |
| [D/1] - 1.4 | D | 1 | 1.4 |
| [E/3] - 33 | E | 3 | 33 |
| [F/4f] - 1.2.1.2.1 | F | 4f | 1.2.1.2.1 |
| [GG/4] - 1.2.1.4.2 | GG | 4 | 1.2.1.4.2 |